# error = "sh: /root/bin/ffmpeg: Permission denied

Tags: php, linux, ffmpeg

Ffmpeg install location.

Hi All i am running Centos 6.6 and i installed ffmpeg using this guide following each step.

http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Centos

But when i try and run.

```
$output = shell_exec("cd {$targetDir} && /root/bin/ffmpeg -i {$fileName} {$wav} 2>&1");
```

I get

> sh: /root/bin/ffmpeg: Permission denied

After reading through lots of post i believe i should not have installed ffmpeg in /root/bin/

How do i install it in say /usr/local/bin ?

I ran this.

> PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$HOME/ffmpeg_build/lib/pkgconfig" ./configure
>   --prefix="$HOME/ffmpeg_build" --extra-cflags="-I$HOME/ffmpeg_build/include" --extra-ldflags="-L$HOME/ffmpeg_build/lib" --bindir="$HOME/bin" --pkg-config-flags="--static" --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265

Can someone let me know who i would do this thanks.

Comment: You're pointing at `$HOME/bin` so if you are loggedin as root `$HOME` is most likely `/root`.  So maybe replace `$HOME` with `/usr/local` and it will be in `/usr/local/bin`

Comment: Hi @AbraCadaver so for the whole tutorial shall i change everywhere is says $HOME/bin to /usr/local/bin ?

Comment: You can try but I think only `--bindir` needs to be changed.

Comment: Thanks @AbraCadaver i managed to get it all working and wrote a little tutorial to remind me https://s3bubble.com/installing-ffmpeg-on-centos-6-6-in-usrlocalbin/

Comment: You can just move the resulting binary to wherever you need it (also check to sure the particular user and/or group can execute it).